# Covariant derivative of tetrad/vielbein

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I am learning about the tetrad basis for manifolds from this lecture [notes](https://www.d.umn.edu/%7Evvanchur/2013PHYS5551/Chapter3.pdf). On pg 52, the spin connections ${{w_\mu}^a}_b$ are defined as
$${{w_\mu}^a}_b=e^a_\nu e^\lambda_b\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\lambda}-e^\lambda_b\partial_\mu e^a_\lambda,$$

where the coordinate basis vectors $\hat{e}_\mu$ and tetrad basis vectors $\hat{e}_a$ are related by
$$\hat{e}_\mu=e^a_\mu\hat{e}_a,$$
$$\hat{e}_a=e^\mu_a\hat{e}_\mu.$$

The author claimed that the first equation is equivalent to $$\nabla_\mu e^a_\nu=0.$$
How can this be shown to be true?

Comment: Have you tried working out the last equation both in terms of the spin and the ordinary Christoffel symbols?

Comment: @NDewolf I am confused about how to do this because I'm not sure what object $e^a_\nu$ is. Is it the components of a rank 2 tensor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply calculate $\nabla_{\mu} e^{a}_{\nu}$ as you usually would (Eq. (3.178) in the notes you're using):
$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{\mu} e^{a}_{\nu} &= \partial_{\mu} e^{a}_{\nu} - \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\eta}e_{\eta}^{a}+ w_{\mu}{}^{a}{}_{c}e^{c}_{\nu} \\
&=\partial_{\mu} e^{a}_{\nu} - \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\eta}e_{\eta}^{a} + e^a_\eta e^\lambda_c\Gamma^\eta_{\mu\lambda} e^c_{\nu} -e^\lambda_c\partial_\mu (e^a_\lambda) e^{c}_{\nu} \\
&= \partial_{\mu} e^{a}_{\nu} - \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\eta}e_{\eta}^{a} + e^a_{\eta}\Gamma^{\eta}_{\mu \nu} - \partial_{\mu} e^{a}_{\nu} 
=0 \ ,
\end{align}
$$
where we've just used the standard definitions of the covariant derivative, spin connection and the tetrad with $e^{a}_{\mu} e_{a}^{\nu} = \delta^{\nu}_{\mu}$ and $e^{a}_{\mu} e_{b}^{\mu} = \delta^{a}_{b}$.

Comment: This seems to be treating $e^a_\nu$ as the components of a rank 2 tensor? I thought it is the components of a rank 1 tensor (vector) since $\hat{e}_\mu=e^a_\mu\hat{e}_a$, which is similar to $\vec{V}=V^a \hat{e}_a$?

Comment: It's a linear map that sends the coordinate basis to the local basis.